# Unable to get the value of JSON - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I tried to get the value of "seed" from json response. But i am getting nil.

Json Response:

```
{
        "response": {
            "params": {
                "rows": "20",
                "defType": "abc",
                "seed": "381786611"
            }
        }
    }
```

Swift Parsing:

```
if let responseHeader:AnyObject = object?["response"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let t = (responseHeader["params"] as? NSDictionary){
       let t1 = t["seed"] as? String
       println("result is \(t1)") // This returns nil
     }
}
```

Json Parsing

```
 func processJsonToDictionary(object:AnyObject?) -> AnyObject?{
        if object != nil {
            if let data: AnyObject = object {
                var parseError: NSError?

                var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(object as NSData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError) as? NSDictionary
                if(parseError != nil){
                    return parseError
                }
                else{
                    return jsonResult
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I am not able to get the value of t1. it always returns nil. 
How can i get the value.

Also, I put a breakpoint and tried to print the value of t1. But the Xcode Keeps crashing. Why?

Comment: I doubt that "Xcode keeps crashing". Is it rather **your code** that keeps crashing?

Comment: i tried to print the value of t1 in console(po t1). Xcode quits and threw the error message in dialog with two options (OK and Reopen)

Comment: The same code works for me, how did you parse the JSON ?

Comment: Please check your JSON result here after that go ahead. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ will help you.

Comment: i am getting the value of t as NSDictionary(contains 3 key value pairs). But t1 returns nil

Comment: seems t["seed"] not getting converted to String, make sure you got proper value of t, and if NSDictionary not really required try replacing NSDictionary with Dictionary<String, String>

Comment: i think it is not an issue with string conversion. I tried to print t["seed"] as AnyObject. But still it return nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think the major problem here is only accessing a JSON object in swift.

```
var error: NSError?
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary
let resp = jsonDict["response"] as? NSDictionary
let params = resp?["params"]?["seed"]
let seed = params!! as NSString
```

This is just to show you how a JSON object is accessed in swift. You can ofcourse change it according to your needs to remove unwanted Optional Chaining.

Answer (score 0):

For easy JSON manipulation in Swift you could try [this](https://github.com/nakkoservices/nkjson) little library. It seems pretty easy and you could do this:

```
var dictionary: [String: AnyObject]!
if let json = NKJSON.parse(yourNSDataObject) {
    dictionary <> json[NKJSON.rootKey]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First confirm that the response which you are getting is in json format or in string format.
For json parsing you can use swifty json pod